# Html Agility Pack perform search on another website and parse

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am trying to create tracking page which will make search on multiple websites and parse the results. So far I created the controller and view but it is not working. Any ideas how to approach?

My cshtml

```html
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <input ID="TextBox1" runat="server">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ID="Button1"
                runat="server" Text="ara" onclick="Button1_Click"></button>

        <label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></label>
    </div>
</form>
```

and controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Net;  // HttpWebRequest
using System.IO;  // Stream
using HtmlAgilityPack;  // Html parse
using System.Text;  // Encoding

namespace Nop.Web.Controllers
{
    public class ContainerTrackingController : Controller
    {
        // GET: ContainerTracking
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}

namespace arkasline
{
    class Program
    {
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Uri ur = null;
            Label1.Text = "";

            // Gets results from Arkasline
                // Prepare query on Arkasline
                string arkaslinesearch = "http://tracking.arkasline.com/ContainerTracking/" + "&q=";

                // Adding query to search
                ur = new Uri(arkaslinesearch + TextBox1.Text);

                // Sending request to Arkasline
                HttpWebRequest arkaslinerequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ur);
                // Getting response from Arkasline
                HttpWebResponse arkaslineget = (HttpWebResponse)arkaslinerequest.GetResponse();
                // Encoding request
                Encoding getencode = Encoding.GetEncoding(arkaslineget.CharacterSet);
                // Reading Respose
                StreamReader arkaslinestream = new StreamReader(arkaslineget.GetResponseStream(), getencode);

                // Saving response as string
                string html = arkaslinestream.ReadToEnd();

                // Parsing response
                HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
                doc.LoadHtml(html);

                // Response on selected nodes
                HtmlNodeCollection links = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id=\"cphMain_pnlMessage\"]/table/tbody/tr/td");

                // Adding results to Label1
                Label1.Text += "Result :<br />";
                // counting
                int i = 1;
                try
                {
                    Label1.Text += "<br /><br />";
                }
                catch (Exception exp)
                {
                    Label1.Text += "<font color=\"red\"> No Results found! </font> <br /><br />";
                }
        }

        private class Label1
        {
            public static string Text { get; internal set; }
        }

        private class TextBox1
        {
            public static string Text { get; internal set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the problem ?

Comment: It is not working at all :)

Comment: Solved. Changed the whole approach